# Asterisk randomizer

Tags: random, asterisk

Please how can i solve this task? 
A call comes to Asterisk server, a random "x" number (1 - 100 is generated), 
if the first two digits in the called number is small or equal to the number 50 from the generated number at that moment, let the Asterisk answer and play a file, if it is big from 50 (50 is the random generated number) 
let the Asterisk drop the call. 
Please who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk have function RAND

```
Asterisk func rand
Synopsis:
Choose a random number in a range

Description:

  RAND([min][,max])

Choose a random number between min and max. Min defaults to 0, if not
specified, while max defaults to RAND_MAX (2147483647 on many systems).
```

Also you need read about asterisk dialplan and gotoIf function

```
GotoIf(condition?[label1]:label2)

Go to next step (or label1 if defined) if condition is true or to label2 if condition is false.

Either label1 or label2 may be omitted (in that case, we just don't take the particular branch), but not both.

condition is just a string. If the string is empty or "0", the condition is considered to be false. If it is anything else, the condition is true. This is designed to be used together with expression syntax.
```

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+rand

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+GotoIf

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you want and the simplest way I can think is add the following line to your existing dialplan:

```
ExecIf($[ ${RAND(1,100)} < 50 ]?HangUp():Playback(youraudiofile))
```

**Explaining further:** This line will test the value returned from the function RAND, if it return 1 to 49 the ExecIf application will execute the command HangUp(), if the value is higher than 50 it will execute the command Playback to playback the given audio file name and then move on to the next dialplan line.

Don't forget to replace 'youraudiofile' with the name of your actual audio file that should be placed on your asterisk sound folder (tipically /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/).